# Closing a sheet programmatically

Tags: swift, macos

I have a couple of processes that can take several seconds to complete and I wanted to have a sheet open in my main application window displaying an indeterminate ProgressWheel and a message saying that the process is underway. I want the sheet to close when the process has completed.

I was trying to implement that by performing a segue to the sheet and sending it two string values in my prepare(for segue) – a waitingMessage, so the sheet can display the name of the process that is underway, and a waitingState... that would be either "starting" or "ending". When my sheet ViewController receives a "starting" state it would just display the ProgressWheel and message, and when it receive the "ending" state it would dismiss itself.

Here's what I'm trying but the sheet won't dismiss, even though it is receiving the "ending" message – its just displays and the entire application won't continue.

```
import Cocoa

class WaitingViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var waitingProgressWheel: NSProgressIndicator!
    @IBOutlet weak var waitingMessageLabel: NSTextField!
    
    var waitingMessage : String = ""
    var waitingState : String = ""

    
    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            let incoming = representedObject as! (String, String)
            waitingMessage = incoming.0
            waitingState = incoming.1
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        waitingProgressWheel.startAnimation(self)
        waitingMessageLabel.stringValue = waitingMessage
        if waitingState == "ending" {
            waitingProgressWheel.stopAnimation(self)
            waitingMessageLabel.stringValue = "Done."
            dismiss(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant part of my prepare(for segue)

```
    override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "waiting" {
            var waitingInfo : (String, String) = ("","")
            waitingInfo.0 = waitingSegueMessage
            waitingInfo.1 = waitingSegueState
            (segue.destinationController as! WaitingViewController).representedObject = waitingInfo
        }
    }
```

Here is my updated sheet view controller:

```
import Cocoa

class WaitingViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var waitingProgressWheel: NSProgressIndicator!
    @IBOutlet weak var waitingMessageLabel: NSTextField!
    
    var processWaitingMessage : String = ""
    var processWaitingState : ViewController.waitingState = .beginning
    var isDone : Bool? {
        didSet {
            if isDone! {
                dismiss(self)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            let incoming = representedObject as! (String, ViewController.waitingState)
            processWaitingMessage = incoming.0
            processWaitingState = incoming.1
            if processWaitingState == .ending {
                isDone = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        waitingProgressWheel.startAnimation(self)
        waitingMessageLabel.stringValue = processWaitingMessage
        if processWaitingState == .ending {
            waitingProgressWheel.stopAnimation(self)
            waitingMessageLabel.stringValue = "Done."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the code both properties in the sheet are set once in the segue. Who does change the values? You might have to add `didSet` observers and move the value check from viewDidLoad (which is called only once) to the property observer. And for multiple states enums are more appropriate  than string literals.

Comment: @vadian Yes, enums are certainly a more sensible way to handle that - thanks. (I've made that change.) The values are changed in the main view controller. When the process ends it performs the segue again, with the .ending value (instead of .beginning, which it is when the segue is first performed.) What I've now done feels convoluted but it still doesn't work. My isDone variable is changing as expected but dismiss(self) isn't closing the sheet.

Comment: You must send dismiss to the presenting view controller not itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is wrong.

You have to update the state from the presenting view controller. To be able to do that you need a reference.

In `ViewController` add a property

```
weak var waitingSheet : WaitingViewController?
```

in `WaitingViewController` add a function

```
func updateState(_ state:  ViewController.waitingState) {
    switch state {
        case .beginning: 
           waitingProgressWheel.startAnimation(self)
           waitingMessageLabel.stringValue = "Beginning"

        case .ending: 
           waitingProgressWheel.stopAnimation(self)
           waitingMessageLabel.stringValue = "Ending"

        case .isDone:
           dismiss(self)
    } 
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` update the state to `beginning`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateState(.beginning)
}
```

Back in `ViewController` assign the reference to the sheet to `waitingSheet` in `prepareForSegue` (the predefined `representedObject` is not needed)

```
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "waiting" {
        waitingSheet = segue.destinationController as? WaitingViewController
    }
}
```

and update the state from any place in `ViewController`

```
waitingSheet?.updateState(.ending)
```

and

```
waitingSheet?.updateState(.isDone)
```

The weak property sets itself to `nil` after the sheet has been deallocated

Comment: thank you for your help - and for that very clear explanation. This really helped to fill in a few gaps in my understanding of working with view controllers. Very much appreciated.